# Authenticate MSAL to get access token using SAML2 authentication

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal, msal

My goal is to get `access token` to authorize the users to access `microsoft graph api`. Unfortunately, I have to use `SAML2` for authentication which can't be use to access Microsoft Libraries. I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-token-exchange-saml-oauth) saying:

> The general strategy is to add the OIDC/OAuth stack to your app. With
> your app that implements both standards you can use a session cookie.
> You aren't exchanging a token explicitly. You're logging a user in
> with SAML, which generates a session cookie. When the Graph API
> invokes an OAuth flow, you use the session cookie to authenticate.
> This strategy assumes the Conditional Access checks pass and the user
> is authorized.

What I understand is it is possible to use `SAML2 auth token` and authenticate `MSAL` to get `access token` to be used on calling `Microsoft Graph API` and other microsoft libraries. I can't find any `session cookie` that mentioned in the article. What I have upon logging into `SAML` is **assertion, claims (tenantid, object identifier, identity provider) and other claims**. Maybe I can use it to authenticate `MSAL`? But I can't find any documentation how to achieve it.

I am new in `SAML`. Can anyone give light to me.